# Rails + Carrierwave + Jquery Fileupload +simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progress-bar, jquery-file-upload

I want to make a simple form to upload an audio file. And i want to show a progress bar of the file uploading when the user submits the file. I only want to submit one file at a time.

My _upload.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for Sound.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :fichier, name: 'sound[fichier]', :required => true %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => 'Titre', :size => 10, :required => true %><br />
    <%= f.submit 'Envoyer' %>
<%end%>
<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
```

My Js file:

```
$('#new_sound').submit(function() {
    $('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        progress: function (e, data){
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        },
    });
});
```

EDIT: (I realize that i forgot my question) Actually it's not really a question it's just i don't get why it didn't work. With this js: it works but i want to wait until the user hits submit before the file is uploaded.

```
$(function () {
    $('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data){
            data.submit();
        },
        progress: function (e, data){
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. Which jquery and fileupload version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/n0ne/Rails-Carrierwave-jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Hey, I have run into the same problem. Where have you entered the JS snippets? inside the form?

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet you are binding the submit function on your form that I'm assuming has an id of #new-sound.

Update your second snippet to reflect that. Should look something like this.

```
$('#new_sound').submit(function() {
    $('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data){
            data.submit();
        },
        progress: function (e, data){
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        },
    });
});
```